# MVC Validation not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

not sure if this is to be expected but it was a surprise to me..

I am strongly typing a view with RegistrationViewModel, but when I attempt to submit the form, the validation incorrectly validates in 2 places.

1. The email field doesnt throw a validation error when I enter "Test".
2. The password validator says that the passwords dont match when they do.

Anyone know why this is happening?

ViewModel class:

```
 public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public RegisterModel RegistrationData { get; set; }
    ...     
}
```

The validation attributes are on the properties of the RegistrationData class:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The Password and Confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First name must be between 2 and 20 characters.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Last name must be between 2 and 20 characters.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model PropertyManager_MVC.Areas.Account.ViewModels.RegistrationViewModel
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Email)
        </div>
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegistrationData.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegistrationData.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationData.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to server-side validation?

Comment: No, the client side validation

Comment: Client side validation and unobtrusive js are both enabled in the webconfig.

Answer (score 2):

Add this Regular expression to Email Property and it will take care of it.

```
  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
  [Display(Name = "Email address")]
  [RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\\.[a-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email")]
  public string Email { get; set; }
```

Add a Required Attribute in front of the Confirm password field.

```
  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Password)]
  [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
  [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
  public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Scottgu's example to handle this.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Comment: Thanks that worked - so what does the DataType.Email do then?

Comment: @Greg - DataType attributes do not affect validation, but rather Display and Editor Templates.  DataType.Password causes the DisplayTemplate to format the password as a mailto: link when using Html.DisplayFor.  You can also override this and create your own Email template if you so desire.

Comment: Although is was working when I first tested it, the validation errors are back ( even though the changes are still in place.) Sorry Shyju, I have marked your answer down again. I need to find the solution for this.

Comment: @Greg : I guess there is some other problem in your code then. The code i provided will work as i am using the same in some apps and it works fine. provide your error details and we will work on that.

Comment: @Shyju - thanks for the reply.. I don't have any other code to do with validation. Only the compare attributes on the model class. Anyway, how could other code "override" the validation behaviour?

Comment: I have tested this problem in a new project - with no code other than the RegisterModel replaced with a view model. It still breaks.